# Como manter estado de um select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html-select

Pode ser em jquery ou angularjs a ajuda.

Tenho o seguinte picklist (feito na mão):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="form group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-3">Selecionar Empresas:</label>
         <select id="select1" name="select1" multiple="multiple">
            <option ng-repeat="c in clientes" value="{{c.idCliente}}" ng-click="atribuirUm($index, c)">{{c.razaoSocial}}</option>                            
          </select>

         <select ng-model="listaEmpresas" id="select2" name="select2" multiple="multiple">
              <option selected="selected" ng-repeat="c2 in clientes2" value="{{c2.idCliente}}" ng-click="limparUm($index, c2)">{{c2.razaoSocial}}</option>                              
         </select>                               
 </div>
```

Antes, eu precisava só do valor em clientes2 para trabalhar os dados em outros momentos.

Agora, preciso manter o estado do primeiro select e do segundo, sempre que carregar a página, preciso saber o que ficou do lado direito e do lado esquerdo.

Como posso com este código, adaptar isto?
Qualquer info é válida, obrigado !

```
/**
 * Trabalhando o componente picklist
 */
$scope.clientes2 = [];      
$scope.atribuirUm = function(index, c) {
    var cliente = {};
    cliente.idCliente = c.idCliente;
    cliente.razaoSocial = c.razaoSocial;
    $scope.clientes2.push(cliente);
    $scope.clientes.splice(index, 1);
};
$scope.limparUm = function(index, c2) {
    $scope.clientes2.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.clientes.push(c2);       
};
```

Comment: Crie um novo elemento e copie os valores para ele. Já tentou isso? Veja: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: Outra dica: Vai ser uma tentação, mas se você está utilizando AngularJs, evite ao máximo recorrer à jQuery. No começo eu sempre tentava resolver com jQuery, especialmente por que era usuário fiel dele, mas hoje percebo que não é necessário utilizá-lo.

Comment: Celsom, mas e quando eu dou o refresh na página, não fica o valores que guardei.
Entendi, obrigado.

Comment: Ai você precisa fazer algum tipo de armazenamento, ou em banco ou em cache. Mas isso é relativo.. depende do seu fluxo. Em alguns casos, não é nem permitido salvar em cache, somente se for em seu banco.. Mas vai depender do seu fluxo.

Comment: Por ser no client, você pode passar por query string ou salvar no cookie.